# for each index in array,return smaller number

Tags: arrays

I have a given array and, I need to return an array that in each cell of the first array there is a one smaller number. for example
`[3,4,2,10]`
the output should be
`[2,3,1,9]`

the complexity should be `O(n*log(n))`

I would appreciate any help

Comment: We can only help if you show us what you have got already.

Comment: Besides, is that small `o`?

Comment: no.it should be upper O

Comment: Ok, please note that there is a difference between them: `Big-O
means “is of the same order as”. The corresponding little-o
means “is ultimately smaller than”`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do better then `O(n log n)`, here a pseudocode:

```
subOne( array[])
      n=arrayLength
      for i=1 to n
         array[i]=array[i]-1
return array
```

running time: `O(n)`

---

If you insist for `O(n log n)`, you also can sort the array using [merge sort](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=merge+sort&oq=merge+s&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.6126j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

```
mergesort(Array m)
{
     if length(m) ≤ 1
         return m
     else
     {
         middle = length(m) / 2
         for each x in m up to middle
             add x to left
         for each x in m after middle
             add x to right
         left = mergesort(left)
         right = mergesort(right)
         result = merge(left, right)
         return result
     }
}
```

Total: `O(n)`+`O(n log n)`=`O(n log n)`

Comment: But is't not O(n log(n)) XD